# I want to update a document with multiple queries in a collection in mongo db using java

Tags: java, mongodb

When I am trying to update with the below code , my collection is not getting updated.

> **Collupdate.java**

```
DBCollection coll = mco.getCollection("Categories");    
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();    
searchQuery.append("org_Id", org_Id);    
searchQuery.append("SerialNumber", SerialNumber);    
BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();    
newDocument.append("categoryName", categoryName);    
BasicDBObject setQuery = new BasicDBObject();    
setQuery.append("$set", newDocument);
coll.update(searchQuery, setQuery);
```

This is my sample document where I am trying to update this record with org_id and serial number and I don't want to insert a new document when the query doesn't exist

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6eb29cc9c484aec5fdec79"),
    "created_time" : "03:25",
    "SerialNumber" : 1,
    "org_Id" : "TES-VBILL-001",
    "created_date" : "08/11/2018",
    "categoryName" : "Tea",
    "categoryDescription" : "Tea"
}
```

I am new to mongodb, can someone please help.

Comment: Can you share how the collection looks like? For example, if the document that answers the query does not exist in the collection it will not be inserted unless you use `upsert: true` in the update settings

Comment: This is my sample document  where I am trying to update this record with org_id and serial number and I don't want to insert a new document when the query doesn't exist{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6eb29cc9c484aec5fdec79"),
    "created_time" : "03:25",
    "SerialNumber" : 1,
    "org_Id" : "TES-VBILL-001",
    "created_date" : "08/11/2018",
    "categoryName" : "Tea",
    "categoryDescription" : "Tea"
}

Comment: That's a good start, what about the rest of the code? What is the type of `mco`? What are the types of `SerialNumber`, `categoryName`,

Comment: Also, how do you initialize mco? 
When I tired to run `db.getCollection('Categories').update({"org_Id":"TES-VBILL-001", "SerialNumber": 1}, {"$set": {"categoryName":"QQ"}})` in mongo shell it worked (note that `SerialNumber`'s value type is a number and not a string, maybe that is the issue?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SerialNumber**-datatype must be number , I observe its String in your query. Please check it. Correct it and update.